# Duplicate toastr error messages

Tags: javascript, toastr

I am using the `Toastr 2.1` JavaScript library to display transient user input validation error messages. I set `preventDuplicates` option to true. It is not working -- I still see duplicate messages when users click validate button in rapid succession (clicks are faster than 'timeout').

Here are my toastr defaults:

```js
function getDefaults() {
    return {
        tapToDismiss: true,
        toastClass: 'toast',
        containerId: 'toast-container',
        debug: false,

        showMethod: 'fadeIn', //fadeIn, slideDown, and show are built into jQuery
        showDuration: 300,
        showEasing: 'swing', //swing and linear are built into jQuery
        onShown: undefined,
        hideMethod: 'fadeOut',
        hideDuration: 1000,
        hideEasing: 'swing',
        onHidden: undefined,

        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
        iconClasses: {
            error: 'toast-error',
            info: 'toast-info',
            success: 'toast-success',
            warning: 'toast-warning'
        },
        iconClass: 'toast-info',
        positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
        timeOut: 5000, // Set timeOut and extendedTimeOut to 0 to make it sticky
        titleClass: 'toast-title',
        messageClass: 'toast-message',
        target: 'body',
        closeHtml: '<button>&times;</button>',
        newestOnTop: true,
        preventDuplicates: true,
        progressBar: false
    };
}
```

Do i need to make any other changes to prevent duplicate error messages?

Comment: Why is user clicking the validate button in rapid successions?

Comment: Users can make changes and click validate button again, this duration could be shorter than toastr message timeout.

Comment: Any update here mate? Did you manage to solve the problem? The demo on CodeSeven works fine but I can't seem to get it working in my project either.

Answer (score 15):

this may help

```
toastr.options = {
"preventDuplicates": true,
"preventOpenDuplicates": true
};

toastr.error("Your Message","Your Title",{timeOut: 5000});
```

Comment: Yes, this helped me : 

    this.toastr.toastrConfig.preventDuplicates = true;

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's working as expected

```
preventDuplicates: Prevent duplicates of the **last toast**.
```

Perhaps this is the property you are looking for?

```
preventOpenDuplicates: Prevent duplicates of open toasts.
```

Comment: For anyone else wondering why this isnt in their toastr.min.js file, this seems to only be in the angular-js port of toastr not vanilla

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it turned out that toastr preventDuplicates option does not work for array messages (current version 2.1.1). You need to convert the array to string using join.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same requirements as you. Below is my implementation. See if it can help you.

```js
function hasSameErrorToastr(message){

  var hasSameErrorToastr = false;

  var $toastContainer = $('#toast-container');
  if ($toastContainer.length > 0) {
    var $errorToastr = $toastContainer.find('.toast-error');
    if ($errorToastr.length > 0) {
      var currentText = $errorToastr.find('.toast-message').text();
      var areEqual = message.toUpperCase() === currentText.toUpperCase();
      if (areEqual) {
        hasSameErrorToastr = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return hasSameErrorToastr;
}

//Usage
var message = 'Error deleting user';
if (hasSameErrorToastr(message)) {
    toastr.error(message, title, errorToastrOptions);
}
```

The code is to check whether there are existing error toastr which has the same message being displayed. I will only fire the toastr.error if there is no existing instance of the same error on display. Hope this helps. The code can be refactored futher more but I'll leave it like this so that its more easier to understand for others.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue **ngx-toastr** and resolved by adding the below code in my module file.

```
ToastrModule.forRoot({
  maxOpened: 1,
  preventDuplicates: true,
  autoDismiss: true
})
```

Also, if lazy loading is implemented, then you need to add the same lines of code to your parent module file also as I've added in my app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

```
imports: [
  ToastrModule.forRoot({
    timeOut: 10000,
    positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
    preventDuplicates: true,
  }),
],
```

this is also present in npm for `ngx-toastr` documentation. you can add it in your app module.ts to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

this may help.

```
var config = {
    maxOpened: 1,
    timeOut: 100
}
```

put it in your toastr config.and it should work.opened toastr is made to 1,and timeout set to 100.

Answer (score 0):

Search `preventDuplicates` in **toastr.min.js** and change

```
preventDuplicates:!1
```

to

```
preventDuplicates:1
```

Comment: Please never edit code in an minified file, you should use the possibility setting the option like `toastr.options.preventDuplicates: true;` instead. If you edit the code within the file and later you'll update the file, your code is removed. Basically you're editing core files in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add preventDuplicates:1 to

```
toastr.options = {
  maxOpened: 1,
  preventDuplicates:1,
  autoDismiss: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this in the constructor and it worked for me

```
this.toastr.toastrConfig.preventDuplicates = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
toastr.options.preventDuplicates = true;
```